# Appending to a List

Tags: python, list

```
L = ['abc', 'ADB', 'aBe']

L[len(L):]=['a1', 'a2'] # append items at the end...
L[-1:]=['a3', 'a4'] # append more items at the end...
```

... works, but 'a2' is missing in the output:

```
['abc', 'ADB', 'aBe', 'append', 'a1', 'a3', 'a4']
```

Comment: Why not use python's list append and extend functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the -1 is pointing at the last element of the list, which gets overwritten by 'a3'.  As described [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html), you can do a

```
list.extend(['a3', 'a4'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `L.append` (for a single element) or `L.extend` (for a sequence) -- there's absolutely no call for playing fancy "assign-to-slice" tricks (especially if you don't master them!-).  The slice `[-1:]` means "last element **included** onwards" -- so, by assigning to that slice, you're obviously "overwriting" the last element!

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with:

```
L.append('a1')
```

or

```
L += ['a1', 'a2']
```

Comment: append, but I'm learning so testing out various method; + creates a new list so its slower than changing in-place.

Comment: + may create a new list, but += as posted by @Pynt does not.

Answer (score 1):

to append items to a list, you can use +

```
L + ["a1","a2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 3rd assignment is overwriting the 'a2' value.

Perhaps you should be using a more straightforward method:

```
L = ['abc', 'ADB', 'aBe']
L += ['a1', 'a2']
L += ['a3', 'a4']
Etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the extend method

```
L = ['abc', 'ADB', 'aBe']
L.extend(['a1', 'a2'])
L.extend(['a3', 'a4'])
```